# Javascript error regex not a function?

Tags: javascript

I found some code online (stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/5774234/150062) that does exactly what I need. But I can't seem to get it running. I get an error `"'/(\\d+)\\s*(second|min|minute|hour)/g' is not a function (evaluating 'regex(s)')";`

```
var timespanMillis = (function() {
  var tMillis = {
    second: 1000,
    min: 60 * 1000,
    minute: 60 * 1000,
    hour: 60 * 60 * 1000 // etc.
  };
  return function(s) {
    var regex = /(\d+)\s*(second|min|minute|hour)/g, ms=0, m, x;
    while (m = regex(s)) {
      x = Number(m[1]) * (tMillis[m[2]]||0);
      ms += x;
    }
    return x ? ms : NaN;
  };
})();
```

I've never heard of this `regex()` function either? Is it suppose to be something else?

Comment: `regex` is a [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), not a function. The author of that code made a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to be possible, you can replace the call with [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for exact same mechanism:

```
m = regex.exec(s)
```

See http://whereswalden.com/2011/03/06/javascript-change-in-firefox-5-not-4-and-in-other-browsers-regular-expressions-cant-be-called-like-functions/

Answer (score 1):

i think

```
regex.match(value)//or regx.exec(value)
```

is function you are looking for

regex is a RegExp object, not a function. here listing of method and function of [Regular Expressions methods and usage](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml)

if match is not working than tryout .test() method like this

```
var match = /sample/.test("Sample text")
```

or

```
var match = /s(amp)le/i.exec("Sample text")
```

Comment: Replacing it with that doesn't seem to work... Apparently that code doesn't work at all, nor is it intended to. Apparently it's demo code.

Comment: @Steven - than try out .test() method of the object..check the method on given link of answer